# Physical interpretation of a complex potential for a particle in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, probability, complex-numbers, quasiparticles

In Griffiths' *Quantum Mechanics*, it is mentioned in a problem that

> For an unstable particle that spontaneously disintegrates with a lifetime $\tau$, the total probability of finding the particle somewhere should *not* be constant$(=1)$ but should decrease at an exponential rate given by :
>   $$P(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x,t)|^2 dx =e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$$

Now the book says that this mathematical result can be proven if *we assume that the potential V is a complex quantity, say, $V=V_0-i\gamma$* where $V_0$ and $\gamma$ are real and $\gamma \not =0$.

And I have verified it also, that it can be proved hence.

**My question is**:  What is the physical interpretation of this *complex potential* and, apart from mathematical reasons, how can I explain the *above assumption* from a physical aspect?

Comment: a potential with an imaginary part is equivalent to adding the imaginary part to the eigenenergies, $H\psi=(E+i\gamma)\psi$, where $H$ is hermitian. In other words, a complex potential (with constant imaginary part) is the same thing as a complex energy. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/298984/84967, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60185 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178233

Comment: What is a complex energy? We normally deal with real energy. So what do you actually mean by an energy represented by a complex number?

Comment: well, that is addressed in the posts I linked before ;-)